# JBoss Singleton Service Example: Does not expose a singleton object

Tags: java, service, jboss, singleton, ejb

I'm using JBoss 6.2 and am attempting to call a singleton service from a webapp filter.

I've successfully installed and started a singleton service within a clustered environment as outlined by the following quickstart tutorial:

https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/44c8c90/cluster-ha-singleton

We can see that the singleton service has been successfully deployed in the admin console:

http://www.rakkatak.com/so/stackoverflow_question_singletonservice_img1.png

As a supplement to the tutorial, I've added a method count() to my SchedulerBean.java that looks like this:

```
@Remote
@Singleton
public class SchedulerBean implements SessionManagerSingleton {
…

    private int counter;

…


    @Override
    public void getSession() {
        counter++;
        LOGGER.info("SchedulerBean: Counter=" + counter);
    }
}
```

I would like to access the above singleton from a webapp. In my case this is a filter (LoginFilter) that is accessed via a service.jar placed in the JBoss modules directory. This jar contains the following:

/META-INF/jboss-ejb-client.properties
/com/login/filter/LoginFilter.class

jboss-ejb-client.properties contains:

```
remote.connections=node1, node2

remote.connection.node1.host=localhost
remote.connection.node1.port = 9999
remote.connection.node1.connect.timeout = 500
remote.connection.node1.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connection.node2.host=localhost
remote.connection.node2.port = 10099
remote.connection.node2.connect.timeout = 500
remote.connection.node2.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

LoginFilter.java contains:

```
final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) context.lookup("global/jboss-cluster-ha-singleton-service/SchedulerBean!org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.Scheduler");
scheduler.count();
```

Note that org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean interface is on the classpath.

I copy service.jar into $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/login/filter/main and then start up the node1 server. Next I bring up the Login webapp in my browser which is configured to use the above LoginFilter class on node 1:

localhost:8080/v1/login

The output from the Scheduler count method is:

14:58:39,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Scheduler Bean: Counter=1

Following this, I bring up the Login webapp pointing at Node 2 and hit the LoginFilter:

localhost:8180/v1/login

On the console for node 2, I see the following output:

```
16:29:23,183 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=1
```

I was hoping to see 'Scheduler Bean: Counter=2'  as this would mean that SchedulerBean is behaving like a singleton across nodes of a cluster. Does anyone know if this is possible as a part of a Singleton Service or otherwise? Thank you.

---

## Output when repeatedly hitting node 1:

```
17:15:07,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=1
17:15:08,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=2
17:15:09,903 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=3
17:15:11,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=4
17:15:12,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=5
17:15:13,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=6
17:15:14,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=7
17:15:14,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=8
17:15:15,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=9
17:15:16,317 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=10
17:15:18,657 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) SchedulerBean : Counter=11
```

## Output when repeatedly hitting node 2:

```
17:29:43,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=1
17:29:48,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=2
17:29:49,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=3
17:30:04,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=4
17:30:10,254 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=5
17:30:14,524 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=6
17:30:15,291 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=7
17:30:19,969 INFO  [org.jboss.as.quickstarts.cluster.hasingleton.service.ejb.SchedulerBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8180-1) SchedulerBean: Counter=8
```

Comment: are you using different physical severs or the same machine for your JBOSS instances?

Comment: They are 2 different JBoss instances running on the same machine

Comment: It seems some configuration issues. In both cases you get output from your first instance. read the output carefully. It is 127.0.0.1:8080-1 in both cases.

Comment: Good eye! That was a copy paste error but I've put the actual console out above. Sorry about that.

Comment: what is the output when you hit node1 url (localhost:8080/v1/login) again and again? Try this and provide your output.

Comment: Added above as the comments have a char limit